# Can a surface impulse be enough to allow entering orbit with no further propulsion?

Tags: launch, orbital-mechanics, orbit

I want to model a slingshot to space. Ignoring all the impossibility of this, and assuming I could launch anything at any speed, can the projectile enter orbit without any propulsion system?

Comment: A simple rule:  Barring encounters with moons or the like one's orbit includes the last point you applied thrust.

Comment: Fun fact: There are rumors that this has, accidentially, [already happened once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhole_cover#Propelled_into_space), but they are [most likely wrong](http://io9.gizmodo.com/no-a-nuclear-explosion-did-not-launch-a-manhole-cover-1715340946).

Comment: @GuntramBlohm The cover wouldn't enter orbit, it would be sub-orbital but highly elliptic assuming it didn't instantly vaporize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without *a little* propulsion to circularize the orbit.

When giving an initial boost, to orbital speed, you're establishing the new orbit - that passes through the point of launch; arriving "from behind" and "from below". In other words, if you launch something into Earth orbit from the surface, the orbit crosses the surface - your satellite will crash; the periapsis of the orbit is located below the planet's surface (or at best at it, if you launch horizontally).

Your satellite needs to perform a prograde burn when at apoapsis, to raise the periapsis above the atmosphere.

Of course this all is pretty much moot considering your satellite will burn up on ascent if you ever manage to give it enough initial propulsion to reach orbital speed.

Caveat: The little propulsion could come from a gravity assist of the Moon. But then, you need to launch it not just into LEO; you'll need to launch it into a lunar flyby trajectory.

Comment: Oh, also, if you're giving it enough initial impulse to cross Earth's Hill Sphere, it will enter the orbit around the Sun just fine. (by the time it's back to its initial point, Earth will have moved out of the way, so no crash unless you're very unlucky about picking just the wrong orbital parameters.) But no, entering LEO requires moving the periapsis above the surface, and you just can't perform that maneuver while on the surface.

Comment: It's actually possible to launch this way if your spacecraft is big enough.   Put your launcher on the highest practical mountain, make the craft very big and very slender and put a **good** heat shield on it's nose.  Your launch angle is nearly straight up, the craft goes out near the edge of Earth's Hill Sphere and then comes back--you need only enough horizontal velocity to have moved it 4000 miles in this multi-day trip.  Now you do an ordinary aerocapture followed by a circularization burn.  You also need a gun-rated spacecraft!

Comment: @LorenPechtel do I understand correctly this won't work in KSP's patched conics approximation?

Comment: @JanDvorak: It would work just fine, just replace Hill Sphere with Sphere of Influence. Launch beyond Minmus orbit, then perform some 20m/s prograde burn at the apoapsis and you're in orbit.

Comment: Can aerodynamics circularize an orbit?  E.g. ascend with excess speed, use negative lift to translate it into horizontal speed boost?  Of course at best you'd get periapsis inside "top of the atmosphere", so the orbit will decay.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin: As you perform any orbital maneuver, you can affect every point of the orbit except of the one single point where you perform the maneuver. So if you perform a maneuver in atmosphere, the resulting orbit WILL be passing through atmosphere.

Comment: Yes, of course.  But can it avoid the ground (on the first rotation)?

Comment: @Beni: Yes. Imagine it's an airplane, launched nearly horizontally, that just turns descent into ascent on the first reentry (which will be also nearly horizontal.) But that orbit will be decaying rapidly.

Comment: @JanDvorak I just tried this in KSP sandbox mode and something's nutty.  I used Mechjeb to take it straight up to an apoapsis at 80Mm.  I only need 25.4 m/s at apoapsis to not hit atmosphere--that's 1/7th the rotation velocity I launched with yet I'm on a lithobraking trajectory.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Because as your orbital altitude rises, your linear speed drops. Especially so in case of elliptic orbits. Great most of your kinetic energy is transformed into potential energy. At a distant apoapsis the forces acting on your craft are very small, so changing the trajectory is very cheap. (try turning from equatorial to polar orbit, then try that again while in circular LKO!) - note you're not changing the total energy of the craft by much at all; you're merely affecting how much of the potential energy will become kinetic, and how the directions will change.

Comment: @SF. Linear speed drops?  That's not what we see with ballistic trajectories here on Earth.  Gravity takes away your vertical velocity, not your horizontal velocity.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: For ballistics on Earth, Earth is flat. There's no braking force other than air friction for the horizontal direction. Now imagine you orient yourself relative to the orbit such that the orbit "points up" and Earth is "Down below". You enter the span towards apoapsis, at huge "vertical" speed just as your "horizontal" speed was reduced to near standstill. By the time your "horizontal" speed is zero, you're halfway between periapsis and apoapsis and Earth is way far down below. Its horizontal force component is minimal. Vertical is pretty small too.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Now as you approach apoapsis, you're still slowing down vertically but with growing distance even that slowdown rate drops. Meanwhile, not only very distant from Earth, you're closer to the axis coming through the center of its mass, so the horizontal acceleration drops to zilch.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Other approach: you travel the "width" of the ellipse the same distance, but you spend hours near the periapsis, and weeks near the apoapsis. If the orbit is to remain ellipse, the horizontal speed near periapsis must be much, much higher than near apoapsis, to cross the distance in so vastly different time.